# git svn authors duplicate error

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have to migrate our SVN repos to Git (FINALLY !). I don't know SVN very well, so maybe my lack of knowledge on this point is problem. Nevertheless, for now I plan to use `git svn`.

But I have a little issue with authors remapping. I exported all authors list from SVN and created a `authors.txt` file as described by documentation. Example :

```
johnD = John Doe <john.doe@company.ch>
andrewS = Andrew San <andrew.san@company.ch>
rogerF = Roger Federer <roger.federer@company.ch>
johnDAdmin = John Doe <john.doe@company.ch>
```

When I try to convert ours repos with a `authors.txt` file similar to this I one, `git svn` throws the following exception :

> Option authors is ambiguous (authors-file, authors-prog)

Thats probably beacause I want to map 2 SVN authors to 1 git author (`johnD` and `johnDAdmin` are the same person but 2 differents accounts).

I know I could migrate this with by mapping them to 2 git authors and after rewrite history to update authors in git history, but I have tens of duplicates accounts and hundreds of repos to migrate and that would be very fastidous to rewrite history for all those repos and authors.

So, does anyone have an idea on how to do to avoid this error ?

Regards,
Selmir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no problem in mapping different SVN users to the same git user/email.

The problem seems to be that you've used both [`--authors-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn---authors-fileltfilenamegt) and [`--authors-prog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn---authors-progltfilenamegt) options. Use only one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's possible. I forgot to mention that I m using a third-party lib ([svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/) on the top of `git svn` so I'm not really sure about what command is executed behind the scenes. I'm not near my computer right now but I will dig into this and try to see precisely which command is executed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to the solution, I was probably too tired, I kept the `--authors` argument from `svn2git` command when I tried with `git svn` only.